# Socket HTTPS (SSL) - Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, https

I have a following code for using sockets and connecting over https:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    SSLServerSocketFactory factory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(8080);
    String[] suites = serverSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    for (int i = 0; i < suites.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(suites[i]);
    }
    serverSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
    String[] protocols = serverSocket.getSupportedProtocols();
    for (int i = 0; i < protocols.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(protocols[i]);
    }
    while (!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
        socket.startHandshake();
        DataOutputStream ClienteEscribir = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        ClienteEscribir.write("Hi".getBytes());

        ClienteEscribir.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    serverSocket.close();
}
```

Every time a client connects, I am getting this error:

```
SSLv2Hello
SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.1
TLSv1.2
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:541)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:374)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1294)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1321)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
Java Result: 1
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try without `socket.startHandshake();`

Comment: Now there are no errors but the server no write the client, need certificate?

Comment: The error message suggests that the client is talking plaintext to you, not SSL. @Fildor Removing `startHandshake()` can't make any difference: removing it just defers the handshake to the first I/O, which is the very next line of code.

Comment: @EJP I suspected it to be called twice, causing some of the trouble.

Comment: @EJP So, if I understand your comment correctly, you suspect the client to create a non-SSL connection. Is that correct? Waresz, can you verify that the client is pulling up a SSL-Socket? I somehow took that for granted.

Comment: @Fildror It doesn't cause the handshake to happen twice, and it wouldn't cause a problem if it did.

Comment: @WareszDescargas What part of 'plaintext ... not SSL' isn't clear to you?

Comment: @EJP I consulted [SSLSocket docu](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#startHandshake()) and understand why it wouldn't cause a problem. But why wouldn't it cause a second handshake to happen? (No offense, just want to understand it - I'm sure you have a one-sentence explanation) Is it because no data has been sent before the call?

Comment: @Fildor It is because no handshake has been performed yet. The first handshake is performed when you call startHandshake() *or* do some I/O, whichever comes first.